# 'navigate' undefined | React Native | Android | in App.js file

Tags: android, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I am learning React Native and don't have very much experience with this.
I am trying to navigate in the App.js file and it gives "TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined" on this line: this.props.navigation.navigate("BlogScreen", {"postId": notification.data.post_id});
I have tried debugging it and also tried a few solutions already asked for a similar question but none seems to work. The difference b/w those questions and mine I think only is that the navigation code is written in "App.js" file in mine.
I will be truly grateful for any help I can get.

Some configuration info from package.json:

```
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
"axios": "^0.21.1",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"react-redux": "^7.2.2",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
```

And following is my App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import AppNavigation from "./app/src/appnavigation/AppNavigation"
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Store from './app/src/redux/store/Store'
import { MenuProvider } from 'react-native-popup-menu'
import FCMServices from "./app/src/utility/PushNotificationHandler"
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        let obj = FCMServices.getInstance(this.FCMServiceCallback);
        obj.setNavigationInstance(this.props.navigation);
        obj.register(this.onRegister, this.onNotification, this.onOpenNotification)
    }

    FCMServiceCallback = () => {
        console.log("FCMServiceCallback")
    }

    onRegister = (fcmToken) => {
        console.log(fcmToken, "fcmToken")
    }

    onNotification = (notification) => {
        console.log(notification, 'notificationnotificationnotification')
    }

    onOpenNotification = (notification) => {
        this.handleNotificationsClick(notification)
    }

    handleNotificationsClick = (notification) => {
        if (!notification.data) {
            return;
        } else {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("BlogScreen", {"postId": notification.data.post_id});
            console.log(notification, 'notificationClicked')
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={Store}>
            <MenuProvider>
            <AppNavigation />
            </MenuProvider>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

Your App.js don't have the navigation prop. This prop is only given to screens referenced in your Navigator (stack, drawer, ...)

The best way to achieve this is by using [deep linking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/) that gives you a general interface to interact with both incoming and outgoing app links.

There is a [short tutorial](https://medium.com/cybermonkey/deep-linking-push-notifications-with-react-navigation-5fce260ccca2) about it

[Related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094140/correct-way-of-navigation-upon-receiving-push-notification-when-app-is-in-foregr)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the whole Render tree with **NavigationContainer**

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>{/* Rest of your app code */}</NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Would suggest creating a new Root Stack and move your code in the HomeScreen Component to access the navigation prop.
Here's an example of how you can do it.

```
 // In App.js in a new project

import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Helpful links:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation#creating-a-stack-navigator